# How to use these array in php

Tags: php

Can someone explain what is happening in these codes? 
I don't understand how cols and rows are being used.
Thank you

```
$chartdata['cols'][] = array('label'=>'Days Range','type'=>'string');

$chartdata['rows'][] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>$month),array('v'=>$prevyearbal)));
```

how these associative arrays get saved in the two dimensional array?
Is `$chardata['cols'][]` going from row *0* to row *n*?

Comment: Is this code running inside of a loop?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/array#language.types.array.syntax.modifying), assigning to `[]` is basically the same as `array_push` but without the function call.